# “On” or “About” after “infer”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When making an inference, do you say “making an inference on something” or “making an inference about something”?

Comment: I usually make inferences *from* things. Also, I can make an inference *of* X from Y: I inferred an attitude *of* snobbishness *from* his tone of voice.

Comment: A dictionary with example sentences will help here. Where [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inference) includes sentences with a preposition, it's *from.*